# How can this algorithm for in-order tree traversal "climb up" the tree?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, binary-search-tree

I am seeing a lot of tutorials about tree traversals and I am confused by how exactly the in-order algorithm allows us to "climb up" the tree.

For example, in the tree below, I understand that we keep going left until there are no children and then we append the value. But what in the algorithm allows us to "climb back up" to the node of value 2, etc.?

I am struggling to understand this. The algorithm in Python, which I am seeing everywhere, is this:

```
def printInorder(root):
    if root:
        # First recur on left child
        printInorder(root.left)
        # then print the data of node
        print(root.val),
        # now recur on right child
        printInorder(root.right)
```

[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion)? That's what allows the algorithm to go "back up", you're just returning from the recursive call.

Comment: I am familiar, but I am just not sure what "tells the algorithm" that we visited Node 1 and to no longer go to the left. I understand that this is a beginner question for sure.

Comment: It no longer goes to the left when there's no left child. That makes `printInorder(root.left)` equivalent to `printInorder(None)`, which means `if root` will be False.

Comment: Makes sense. But then how does it jump to Node 2? What I'm seeing in the algorithm only allows it to look left and to look to the right, not up.

Comment: It doesn't "go up".  The recursive function says "print my left children, then print myself, then print my right children."  So after all of the left children are printed, those recursive functions exit and the "print myself" bit happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well let me explain this a bit from this perspective. You are aware of the fact that once you  print the root node, then you need to do the same inorder traversal for the subtree having left child as root and the subtree with right child as the root node.

How do we traverse up? It's simply when we get back to the recursive call. Yes it might feel a bit strange but this is how the function call works, once the called function finishes the control goes to parent function and then it finishes the work and the control goes to parent of that.

Now you asked the question,

> what "tells the algorithm" that we visited Node 1 and to no longer go
> to the left

It actually goes to the left of `1` which is basically not a node anymore. It's just `None` now the function sees that you have an `if` statement saying `do the work only if root is not None`. And that's where this function stops calling further. Once it is done it goes back to the parent of it, which is `1`.
Now at `1` after printing `1` then we again call to traverse the `right` child of `1` but again it is `None` so the same thing happens. And then at node `1` we have done everything that we asked the method to do in the `if` block. It goes back to node `2` the parent.

This is how it works. This diagram will explain it clearly:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is super helpful and despite using many recursive algorithms, I now see I had no idea how they truly worked.